# Syntax for rule with multiple pick list

Tags: formula, picklist, compile-error

I'm new to creating validation rules and am having problems with the syntax. I want to trigger an error message if a picklist question is not answered when closing an opportunity.

I have viewed several guides and below is the latest syntax I have tried:

```
AND (
OR (
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"),
ISPICKVAL( Loss_Reason_Pick_ONE__c , ""))
)
```

In plain text, if the opportunity is closed with Case Lost as the reason, but an option hasn't been selected for why (Loss_Reason_Pick_ONE__c) then the error should appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is almost correct, just that you need to make logical corrections in your formula i.e. no need to use `OR` function. Your validation rule should be same as what you have written it in plain text.

So your rule would be, to throw error message when Opportunity's Stage is in "Closed Lost" stage AND no value is selected in Loss_Reason_Pick_ONE__c field i.e. it is left blank.

```
AND (
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"),
    ISPICKVAL(Loss_Reason_Pick_ONE__c,'')
)
```

OR

```
AND (
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"),
    ISBLANK(TEXT(Loss_Reason_Pick_ONE__c))
)
```

PS : It is advisable to use the first approach rather than going for the second one.

You can go through [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5) to know more about various functions that can be used.

Comment: I tried to ISBLANK earlier, but the issue with that is that you can only use this function on multiselect. The second field is just a single select picklist.

Comment: @MartinVanDyke It does work with single select picklist, just that I forgot to add `TEXT` function. Updated the answer, that should work.

Comment: @VijayGanji for single select, `ISPICKVAL(field,'')` would be the "official" way to do that.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for correcting. Updated the answer.